# Newton's first law: unclear multiple choice question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conventions

Everyone knows that a body with no external forces acting on it remains at rest or moves with a constant velocity. But how would you answer the following multiple choice question:

> *Question: A body with no forces acting on it **always**:*
>
> - A.) Remains at rest
> - B.) Undergoes rectilinear uniform motion
> - C.) Neither of the above

Now of course A.) is wrong because of the word **always**. But then is B correct? Does remaining at rest count as uniform motion (with zero velocity)? It seems to me that this question isn't well posed, unless there's an established convention of treating rest as a special case of uniform motion?

Comment: I don't see why remaining at rest shouldn't be a rectilinear uniform motion. Being at rest is dependent on the observer anyway.

Comment: (B) subsumes (A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in assuming that being at rest is considered a special case of rectilinear uniform motion (abbreviated *r.u.m.* hereafter). The closest thing to a *reason* for this convention I can give is this:

It is a nice property to have all observers in inertial frames agree on whether a body is in r.u.m. However, for every such body in r.u.m. (which we shall assume to not have the speed of light), there is an inertial frame in which that body is at rest.

Now, if one now would not consider being at rest as a special case of r.u.m., there would always be one observer that would disagree with the others whether a body undergoes r.u.m. That would make talking about things a lot more awkward.

As such, answer **B** is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A is wrong because the concept of "at rest" implies an arbitrary decision.

The right answer is B which is correct whatever the observer's chosen frame.

Comment: A) says 'remains' at rest. For me as a non-native speaker this implies that the object is at rest in the reference frame at some point. Since it is assumed that there are no forces, it will 'remain' at rest. So, I think it is far from obvious that A) should be marked wrong...

Answer (score -1):

A body with no forces on it always follows a geodesic.

In a gravitational field, two nearby object start at rest with respect to the each other. One is above the other. The separation between them increases.

Neither A nor B is correct.

---

Edit

Thank you pfnuesel. If general relativity is not considered, then B is correct.

An object that starts at rest remains at rest. A is wrong because not all objects start at rest.

RQM is right. Remaining at rest is a special case of r.u.m.

Comment: From the level of the question I assume that GR is not considered here and gravitation is taken as a force, hence the argument with the gravitational field would not be valid. (I didn't downvote, by the way.)